# Do 'destroy' effects count as damage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [The Wanderer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=460964)'s static ability prevent 'destroy' or 'exile' effects from working? In a recent game, I had it out and my opponent tried to cast [Doom Blade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoom%20Blade%5d) on a creature. I argued that it shouldn't work, and he said it should have.

Answer (score 11):

Damage is one of the ways a creature can be destroyed, but it's not the only way. The Wanderer only prevents (non-combat) damage, not other "destroy" effects like Doom Blade.

> 701.7. Destroy
>
> 701.7a To destroy a permanent, move it from the battlefield to its owner’s graveyard.
>
> 701.7b The only ways a permanent can be destroyed are as a result of an effect that uses the word “destroy” or as a result of the state-based actions that check for lethal damage (see rule 704.5g) or damage from a source with deathtouch (see rule 704.5h). If a permanent is put into its owner’s graveyard for any other reason, it hasn’t been “destroyed.”

Comment: In other words if your opponent cast something that said "deal five damage to target creature", then The Wanderer will prevent the damage; it cannot however protect against Doom Blade.

Comment: Since the question is about what counts as damage, not what counts as being destroyed; it would be helpful to list the ways damage can happen. Unfortunately there doesn’t seem to be a simple rule as straightforward as 701.7b, except for damage instead of destroy.